# Transformers gets killed for no reason on linux

Tags: memory-management, nlp, out-of-memory, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

So i'm trying to run inference on a Huggingface model, the model is 6.18gb.
This morning I was on Windows and it was possible to load the model, but inference was very slow so I took a look at DeepSpeed but only available on linux so I switched to Zorin OS.
Now the exact same script gets killed when running

```
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("Cedille/fr-boris", device_map = "auto")
```

What is going on ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try to diagnose with below command:

```
dmesg -T| grep -E -i -B100 'killed process'
```

And you may find out the reason.

```
[Fri Feb 10 21:16:54 2023] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-14313.scope,task=python,pid=1071011,uid=1000
[Fri Feb 10 21:16:54 2023] Out of memory: Killed process 1071011 (python) total-vm:2480280kB, anon-rss:1709008kB, file-rss:4kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:4276kB oom_score_adj:0
```